# Cannot for the life of me reference a variable inside of a list from another class

Tags: c#, json, wpf, list, parsing

I'm trying to set a variable def, to have the value of definition inside of the Definition Class
Here is the class I'm trying to reference.

```
public class Definition
{
   public string type { get; set; }
   //need to get this to def in PlayButton event
   public string definition { get; set; }
   public string example { get; set; }
   public string image_url { get; set; }
   public object emoji { get; set; }

}

public class Root
{
   public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
   public string word { get; set; }
   public string pronunciation { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have the def variable within the event but I dont know how, To do this I have to reference the `DeserializedJSON` variable because it the JSON is being parsed from there into that class but I cant find a way to get it from `DeserializedJSON` to `defs`:

```
//Click PlayButton event
public async void PlayButton_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   //Changing From Start Screen Grid To Quiz Screen Grid
   QuizScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   StartScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   //Running game logic once to start game up
   string word = RandomWord();
   definitionUnformatted = await Define(word);
   //Deserialising JSON
   Root DeserializedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(definitionUnformatted);

   string def = //help here pls

      DefinitionBox.Text = def;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help, I just hope this is a simple oversight I'm making that I can learn from.

EDIT: @crowcoder asked for an example of the JSON

```
{
    "definitions": [
        {
            "type": "noun",
            "definition": "something shaped like a platter, in particular:",
            "example": "dig out some old platters",
            "image_url": null,
            "emoji": null
        },
        {
            "type": "noun",
            "definition": "a large flat dish or plate for serving food.",
            "example": "arrange the fruit on a serving platter",
            "image_url": "https://media.owlbot.info/dictionary/images/kkkki.jpg.400x400_q85_box-0,0,360,360_crop_detail.jpg",
            "emoji": null
        }
    ],
    "word": "platter",
    "pronunciation": "ˈpladər"
}
```

Comment: according to you class, you get a Root Object, it has a list of definitions, which one do you want ?

Comment: Your `Root` class has a property `definitions`, which is of type `List<Definition>`, From which item in this list do you want to get the value of `definition`?

Comment: can you show a relevant example of the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: @thatguy I'm not sure what you mean, I want the value of definition to be assinged to a variable in "playbutton_click"

Comment: @AthulRaj I'd like to get the value of the "public string definition" inside of the class "Definition" into a variable  in "playbutton_click"

Comment: You have a collection of `Definition` but just one variable. Based on the json that you posted, what is the expected value of `def`?

Comment: the definition of a word from the owlbot api

Comment: it looks like the api returns a list of definitions, it make sense because a word can have multiple definitions.
if you just want to get the definition for the first one returned by the api you could use
DeserializedJSON .definitions.First().definition. you may want to do some null checking on this

Comment: You have two definitions for the word in the example. With that input what is the expected output? A concatenation of the definitions? The first definition?

Comment: the string not the class @Crowcoder

Comment: I don't understand why you can't answer my question. Just edit your question and actually type the words that you expect `def`'s value to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you build a word guessing game. You get the definition of a word from an external API and want to get the first definition that needs to be assigned to `def`.

Since `definitions` is a `List<Definition>`, use the indexer to get the first item.

```
string def = DeserializedJSON.definitions[0].definition;
```

Alternatively, use Linq's `First` method, which does the same.

```
string def = DeserializedJSON.definitions.First().definition;
```

Note, that your `Root` class contains a property `definitions` of type `List<Definition>`, which means you could also have multiple definitions or no definitions at all. In case of multiple definitions you need to decide which one to choose.

The code below checks in advance, if the list is not `null` and if there are definitions in the list. Otherwise, you will get a an exception if the list is `null` or when accessing the first item in case that there are **no definitions**.

```
if (DeserializedJSON.definitions != null && DeserializedJSON.definitions.Count > 0)
   def = DeserializedJSON.definitions[0].definition;
else
   def = "No definition found";
```

Comment: crashes when definitions is null.
can do
def = DeserializedJSON.definitions?.FirstOrDefault()?.definition ?? "No definition"

Comment: @AthulRaj You are right, thank you. I added a simple `null` check, as I do not know if @Lewie is familiar with these operators.